# How does List work in EntityFramework Entity?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have 2 data models:

```
public class Role
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    List<Role> Roles;
}
```

there is my DbContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
    public DbSet<Role> Roles => Set<Role>();
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=database.sqlite");
    }
}
```

but i have troubles with `List<Role>`, when i check db data from viewer, i see that `Users` table does not have any `Roles` in users, but `Roles` table has property `UserID`, it kinda works but only 1 id stored there, how can i fix it?

I need to have multiple roles
and users that has some of these roles

Comment: Are those your **actual** `class` definitions? If so, it won't work as-is because EF can only bind to properties, not fields.

Comment: _"when i check db data from viewer"_ - what viewer?

Comment: The properties should also be `public`

Comment: i actually have public properties, i use 'Db viewer for sqlite' (not sure how it called properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it kinda works but only 1 id stored there, how can I fix it?

It depends on what you actually want. Depending on the app requirements usually user can be assigned only one role or there is a many-to-many relationship between users and roles.

In case if you want user to have only one role then you should reverse the relationship i.e. role has list of users:

```cs
public class Role
{
    // ...
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new();
}

public class User
{
    public int Id  { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

For the many-to-many case there are two main options - specify `List` on both sides and let EF internally create the join table or explicitly configure the join table ([EF Core docs on many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)). For the first case your entities can look like the following:

```cs
public class Role
{
    // ...
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new();
}

public class User
{
    public int Id  { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new();
}
```